# Can we see a plot of our site's Area 51 stats over time?

Tags: support, feature-request

[Our Area 51 statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4861/parenting) have always been excellent, except for "questions per day" which continues to linger around 1-3 q/day.

But this is only a snapshot of *right now.* It would be interesting to see how these values have evolved over time. Is it possible to get a graph of this? Is that something we could request from SE (the company)?

Answer (score 2):

I think one could create a query in:

http://data.stackexchange.com/parenting/queries

I modified this one to span over 36 months:

http://data.stackexchange.com/parenting/query/edit/194173

And got this graph:

[image: parenting questions stats]

Apparently, we are seeing a slow but almsot constant increase in questions since April 2013. If this continues linearly, we'll hit the recommended 300 questions per day around 2018 ;)